# Issue while podspec linting

Tags: ios, cocoapods, repository

I created one pod for facebook login. In the local repository, podspec validated properly. After that, I committed code on my GitHub account.

Then I release a new version and then I performed pod trunk command.

```
pod trunk push FBSDKLoginKit.podspec
```

**This command will one weird error like below.**

> You  are not allowed to push new versions for this pod. The
>   owners of this pod are nlutsenko@me.com and cocoapods@fb.com.

Below is my podSpec.

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
s.name             = 'FacebookLogin'
s.version          = '1.0.0'
s.summary          = 'The Reusable Facebook Login Components for iOS is the easiest way to get data from Facebook.'

s.description      = 'The Reusable Facebook Login Components for iOS is the easiest way to get data from Facebook.'

s.homepage         = 'https://github.com/simformsolutions/FacebookLogin.git'

s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
s.author           = { 'Xxxxx' => '<Email>' }

s.source           = { :git => 
              'https://github.com/simformsolutions/FacebookLogin.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }

s.ios.deployment_target = '10.0'
s.source_files = 'ReuseabelLogInComponets/Classes/*.swift'

s.dependency 'FBSDKLoginKit', '4.30.0'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because someone with email the email nlutsenko@me.com (https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-swift) has registered the pod with the name 'FacebookLogin' before you. So you must choose other name for your new pod.